# VS2010 Database Projects and SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a VS2010 SQL Server 2008 database project for a SQL Server 2008R2 database.  When I attempt to import an existing database a window popups up with the following message "The database that you selected is not supported."

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Note: I have managed to create a database project that happily allowed me to create a table in the master database on the same SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I figured this one out myself.  I think this may be related to my uninstalling some software / database driver that had a connection reference in Visual Studio which was not cleaned up.

Basically to fix the problem I closed Visaul Studio and then deleted this file.
C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView

Here is a link to the question and answers that helped me out:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552006/unable-to-create-data-connection-in-server-explorer

Answer (score 0):

Probably your existing database has different version. Try this: [How to: Change the Target Database Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833254.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.  I am trying to create the project with the SQL Server 2008 Wizard.  A colleague of mine has managed to create the project from his Visual Studio pointing to the same database on my SQL Server 2008R2 so I think either my visual studio has a problem or my database templates have a problem